# No coverage data with `nyc mocha`

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, code-coverage, nyc

Although my tests run perfectly fine with

```
$ cross-env NODE_ENV=test nyc --require babel-register mocha
```

[image]

Everything is zero, and inside the `./coverage` dir there is no coverage  info too :(

My project is very basic (ES2015):

```
./lib.js
./test/lib.spec.js
```

Here is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "istanbul"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and the `.nycrc` file

```
{
  "check-coverage": false,
  "lines": 99,
  "statements": 99,
  "functions": 99,
  "branches": 99,
  "include": [
    "./lib.js"
  ],
  "reporter": [
    "lcov",
  "text-summary"
  ],
  "require": [],
  "extension": [
    ".js"
  ],
  "cache": false,
  "all": false,
  "report-dir": "./coverage"
}
```

I've also made an identical setup using ES5 only with the same result. Any suggestions why I have no coverage ?

UPDATE: Solution can be found [here](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/624)